# DllImport doesn't work as advertised in Mono (Linux, C#)

Tags: c#, linux, mono, dllimport, monodevelop

I'm getting to know Mono development in Linux, in baby steps. I'm trying to call Linux C libraries. [This page](http://www.mono-project.com/Interop_with_Native_Libraries), in theory, tells me how, but when I type the code below in MonoDevelop 2.2.2 (Fedora 13), I get a "Parsing Error (CS8025)" in "private static extern int getpid();". Moreover, the help system doesn't work.

```
using System;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

[DllImport("libc.so")]
private static extern int getpid();

namespace LinuxCaller
{
    class MainClass
    {
        public static void Main (string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine ("Hello World!");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please don't edit your question to include the correct answers by removing the problem code. It then becomes useless to others years later..

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Function definitions cannot appear in the namespace scope in C#.  This includes DLL import definitions.  To fix this just move the function definition inside a type.

```
class MainClass {
  [DllImport("libc.so")]
  private static extern int getpid();

  ...
}
```

Comment: It builds now, but it doesn't find libc.so -- see above.

Comment: @JCCyC is libc.so at the given path and accessible to the process?

Comment: Yes, but intriguingly, it only has 238 bytes. Eek. It contains just some text! I used "libc.so.6" instead and it works now.

Comment: actually, you should use [DllImport("c")] mono does the rest.

Comment: @IanNorton - Do you have a reference for this shortcut?  Does it work uniformly on linux/mac/windows?

Comment: Yes, you can override this using dllmaps at runtime for mono. Windows is less easy.  http://www.mono-project.com/Config_DllMap

Comment: Wow.  Just copied your code but used "libc.dylib" instead (since I'm on a Mac) and it ran like a charm.  C# mono is a very good thing.  Got me excited about programming again.

Answer (score 2):

If you just need to access some common *nix system calls, check out the Mono.Unix namespace which provides wrappers around a lot of functions.

http://www.go-mono.com/docs/index.aspx?link=N%3aMono.Unix

Comment: Actually what I need is to call some UNcommon functions in third-party libraries, but that is indeed useful information.